# Accessing other listbox item controls and properties on button click

Tags: c#, binding

I'm currently binding an xml file to a listbox in C# WPF. Within the itemtemplate I added controls. as follows:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SinglecueTemplate">
            <Grid Height="30" Width="425" Margin="3,3,0,3">
                <Button Content="{Binding XPath=nr}" Width="30" Style="{DynamicResource CUEStyle_Button_Inhoudknopje}" Template="{DynamicResource CUEStyle_singlecueknopnummer}" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="#FFABCCED" Foreground="White" IsEnabled="False"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="name" Margin="54,0,114.667,0" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" Foreground="Gray" Text="{Binding XPath=Name}"/>
                <Button x:Name="playbutton" Width="30" Style="{DynamicResource CUEStyle_Button_Groot}" Template="{DynamicResource CUEStyle_Rondknopje}" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0.55,74.737,-0.55" Content="u" FontFamily="Wingdings 3" Foreground="#FF0178D3" Opacity="1" BorderBrush="#FF0178D3" Click="playcue"/>
                <Button Width="30" Style="{DynamicResource CUEStyle_Button_Groot}" Template="{DynamicResource CUEStyle_Rondknopje}" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0.55,37.071,-0.55" Content="¢" FontFamily="Wingdings 2" Foreground="Gray" Opacity="0.4"/>
                <Button Width="15" Style="{DynamicResource CUEStyle_Button_Groot}" Template="{DynamicResource CUEStyle_kleinloopje}" Height="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,0,0,-5.5" Content="Q" FontFamily="Wingdings 3" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="10.667" Opacity="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" IsEnabled="{Binding XPath=Loop}"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="0,0,114.667,0" Width="81.07" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" Foreground="Gray" Text="03:02:11" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Now when a the playbutton is clicked I want to acces other properties from that listboxitem, for example the text from the text block. I looked up on how to do this and came up with the following:

```
            private void playcue(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                Button playcue = (Button)sender;
                Textbox titel = (Textbox)playcue.DataContext;
                MessageBox.Show(titel);
            }
```

But the code above gives me an error stating that the type Textbox is unknown. Do I have to do something with the datatemplate so that I can acces other items within the template? Or is it possible to access sibling nodes from the datasource?

**UPDATE**

Answer found. Now for future reference:

```
private void playcue(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                Button playcue = (Button)sender;
                XmlElement name = (XmlElement)playcue.DataContext; 
                MessageBox.Show(name.InnerText);

            }
```

Returns all sibling values from the item

If you want to access a specific sibling you can do so:

```
MessageBox.Show(name.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerXml);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is that it's `TextBox` not `Textbox` (C# is case sensitive.)

Second, it's unlikely that your `DataContext` is a `TextBox`. It should be an item in your `ItemsSource` collection. So, if the user clicks the third button in the list, you should be looking at the 3rd item in your `ItemsSource` collection. Since it appears you are using XML as a data source, I would guess that the item should be an `XElement` or an `XmlElement`.

I suggest you change `Textbox titel = (Textbox)playcue.DataContext;` to the following:

```
XElement element = (XElement)playcue.DataContext;
```

or

```
XmlElement element = (XmlElement)playcue.DataContext;
```

You will also need to change your `MessageBox` statement as well.